# How to configure windows to only allow programs in certain folders to be executed?

Tags: windows-7, windows

For example, I'd like to allow only programs in Program Files to be executed, while anything in other folders is restricted or prompts the user for admin password.
Furthermore, how would I allow programs to write to folders, but not allow the user to access these folders directly (For compiling and executing programs)?

I have two accounts, one admin and one standard user on all of the computers.